# Printing binary number giving weird results

Tags: c

I was reviewing bitwise operators and wrote a simple code to print the binary representation of numbers but I am having crazy output, and I have no explanation for it. why is the program not giving me the correct binary numbers ?
Here is the sample output :[image]

and my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pBinary(int x);

int main(void)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
        pBinary(n);
    }
    return 0;
}

void pBinary(int x)
{
    int y = 1 << 31;
    for (int n = 0; n < 32; n++) {
        x & y ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
        y >>= 1;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of text! And your code invokes _undefined behaviour_, see 6.5.7 in the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `int` is 32-bit long, `1 << 31` invokes signed integer overflow, which is *undefined behavior*.

Consider making the value to deal with unsigned.

```
void pBinary(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int y = 1u << 31;
    for (int n = 0; n < 32; n++) {
        x & y ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
        y >>= 1;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

It is safer to use types with defined size. Include `inttypes.h` or `stdint.h` to use `uint32_t`.

```
void pBinary(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t = UINT32_C(1) << 31;
    for (int n = 0; n < 32; n++) {
        x & y ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
        y >>= 1;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have left shifted the number 1 ..31 places. Surely an overflow as by default it is performed over signed number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pBinary(int x);

int main(void)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
        pBinary(n);
    }
    return 0;
}

void pBinary(int x)
{
    unsigned int y = (1u << 31); //avoid overflow
    for (int n = 0; n < 32; n++) {
        (x & y) ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
        y >>= 1;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```