# What is the format specifier for binary in C?

Tags: c, binary, symbols

I have looked all over the place, but I have not found an answer to my question. First of all, I know that the symbol for decimal is `%d`, the symbol for octal is `%o`, and the symbol for hexadecimal is `%x`. What I cannot find, however, is the symbol for binary. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641213/printing-binary-number-giving-weird-results

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of C23, the below function is no longer required. New format specifiers `%b` and `%B` [have been added to printf() and friends to format integers as binary numbers](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2630.pdf)—the former omitting any leading zeros and the latter including them (similar to `%x` and `%X`).

---

**Original answer:**

The reason you're having trouble finding a format specifier for printing integers in binary is because there isn't one. You'll have to write you're own function to print numbers in binary.

So for a single unsigned byte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void print_bin(unsigned char byte)
{
    int i = CHAR_BIT; /* however many bits are in a byte on your platform */
    while(i--) {
        putchar('0' + ((byte >> i) & 1)); /* loop through and print the bits */
    }
}
```

And for a standard unsigned int:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void print_bin(unsigned int integer)
{
    int i = CHAR_BIT * sizeof integer; /* however many bits are in an integer */
    while(i--) {
        putchar('0' + ((integer >> i) & 1)); 
    }
}
```

Adjust the function for larger integers accordingly. Be wary of signed shifting though because the behavior is undefined and entirely compiler dependent.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. If you want to output in binary, just write code to do it.

Comment: more like a comment ?

Comment: It completely answers his question. If a complete answer should be a comment, then it's a bad question. But I don't see anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way. One way, you could make a look-up table that converts a byte to a `const char *` of 1's and 0's. Then you could iterate through the bytes and print out what is in the look-up table.